# MySQL not inserting all rows

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I'm moving posts from my WP blog into a custom website. I made a script to pull out needed columns from the WP SQL-dump, and then loop it into a newly created table. Both the WP table and my database and the custom table uses UTF-8. I've counted the rows I'm getting, both before and after executing the loop inserting the new info. The number of posts is 427, and this is the correct number of posts. However, in the database only 234 posts get inserted, and I suspect it is MySQL not being able to insert certain posts, but I have no idea why. Here is the code:

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'PASSWORD');
$select = mysql_select_db('blog');

mysql_query("
CREATE TABLE posts (
    id int(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    title varchar(250) NOT NULL,
    content longtext NOT NULL,
    date varchar(90) NOT NULL,
    deleted int(1) NOT NULL
)") or die(mysql_error());

$query = mysql_query("SELECT post_date, post_title, post_content FROM sspe_posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish'");

$i = 0;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

    $oldPosts[$i]['title']    = $row['post_title'];
    $oldPosts[$i]['date']     = $row['post_date'];
    $oldPosts[$i]['content']  = $row['post_content'];

    $i++;

}

$size = count($oldPosts);

for ($x = 0; $x < $size; $x++) {

    $title      = $oldPosts[$x]['title'];
    $content    = $oldPosts[$x]['content'];
    $date       = $oldPosts[$x]['date'];

    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO posts (title, content, date, deleted) VALUES ('$title', '$content', '$date', 0)");

}

echo $x;
```

Comment: Check `mysql_error()` on each iteration: `if (!$query) {echo mysql_error();}` That will make it clear which ones fail and why.

Comment: check if your script does not exceed time limit (30 seconds by default)

Comment: Your insert query is vulnerable to sql injection. If your post titles/content contain any quotes (`'`), the queries will break. You're NOT checking for error conditions and are blindly assuming the queries succee - a very BAD thing to do.

Comment: Of course I forgot to use mysql_error()! Also, turning everything into string literals with MRES fixed the problem! Thanks alot guys!

Answer (score 2):

Michael is right about your script not checking whether the query succeeded or failed.
You also have "treat" the parameters you're putting as string literals into the statement with [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://docs.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)

```
for ($x = 0; $x < $size; $x++) {
    $title      = mysql_real_escape_string($oldPosts[$x]['title']);
    $content    = mysql_real_escape_string($oldPosts[$x]['content']);
    $date       = mysql_real_escape_string($oldPosts[$x]['date']);

    $query  = "
        INSERT INTO
            posts
            (title, content, date, deleted)
        VALUES
            ('$title', '$content', '$date', 0)
    ";

    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if ( !$result ) {
        die(mysql_error()."\n".$query);
    }
}
```

But you problem is easier solved with something like

```
INSERT INTO
    posts
    (title, content, date, deleted) 
SELECT
    post_title, post_content, post_date, 0
FROM
    sspe_posts
WHERE
    post_type = 'post'
    AND post_status = 'publish'
```

see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html

Answer (score 0):

If you can lock your table without troubles I think it's better to run:

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO posts (title, content, date, deleted) 
SELECT post_date, post_title, post_content, 0 FROM sspe_posts 
WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish'");
```

And you will avoid loop.